# Google Earth - Balloon at launch

Tags: kml, google-earth

When I open a KML file I would like to have an image/details display in a pop-up balloon automatically.  Typically the user has to physically click the folder/image for the pop-up to appear.

Is there any code that would allow me to have the balloon appear once the KML is launched?

I know how to add an screen overlay and have that appear on the middle of the screen at launch, but you cannot remove it off the screen unless you check it off in the sidebar.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Google provides a few extensions to the standard KML language. One such extension is that exact feature. Adding the element `<gx:balloonVisibility>` with a value of 1 to your Placemark will make the description balloon appear immediately when the KML is loaded.

Note the *gx:* namespace prefix to the element, which is is required as well as the xmlns:gx declaration at the top of the KML file as shown in this example.

Example:

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
 xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">

  <Placemark>
    <name>Eiffel Tower</name>
    <description>
        Located in Paris, France. 

        This description balloon opens 
        when the Placemark is loaded.
    </description>
    <gx:balloonVisibility>1</gx:balloonVisibility>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>2.294785,48.858093,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>

</kml>
```

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#gxballoonvisibility

**BUG:**

This feature worked in older versions of Google Earth, but is broken in Google Earth v7.1.2.2041 (at least confirmed on Windows) if GE launches with such KML it won't auto display the balloon but if GE is already started then opening the KML will auto-popup the balloon description. A bug report has been filed with Google.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I have tried that code and the placemark does not appear immediately as it should, and I have read this has been a problem for others as well.  I found this forum entry - but this doesn't allow you to choose where you want the placemark rather it centers on the middle of the screen.  http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/earth/wFDahOtU69E

Comment: Appears to be a bug in Google Earth v7.1.2.2041 (at least confirmed on Windows) if GE launches with such KML it won't auto display the balloon but if GE is already started and open the KML then it auto-popups the balloon description. This issue has been reported to Google Earth test team.