# KML Balloon will not automatically open

Tags: kml, google-earth

From what I've read to have a placemark balloon automatically open (without the need to click on it) you simply put `<open>1</open>` under the `<placemark>` tag.

I've also seen the `<open>` tag placed other places such as under the `<document>` tag but no matter where I place it the balloon never opens up by itself.

Here's the file I'm using (I placed the `<open>` tag in three different places hoping it would work):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"     xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:location="http://blah.com">
<Document>
    <name>RSSToKml</name>
    <open>1</open>
    <StyleMap id="m_ylw-pushpin">
        <Pair>
            <key>normal</key>
            <styleUrl>#s_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
        <Pair>
            <key>highlight</key>
            <styleUrl>#s_ylw-pushpin_hl0</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <Style id="s_ylw-pushpin">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>1.1</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <hotSpot x="20" y="2" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
        </IconStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id="s_ylw-pushpin_hl0">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>1.3</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <hotSpot x="20" y="2" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
        </IconStyle>
    </Style>

    <Placemark>
        <name>A name</name>
        <open>1</open>
        <description>A description</description>

        <LookAt>
            <longitude>-73.99736287597681</longitude>
            <latitude>40.71745136763278</latitude>
            <altitude>0</altitude>
            <heading>-46.51707308500568</heading>
            <tilt>5.83698745180558</tilt>
            <range>7808.551256710743</range>
            <gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode>
        </LookAt>

        <styleUrl>#m_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        <Point>
            <gx:drawOrder>1</gx:drawOrder>
            <coordinates>-73.9994479424963,40.71617147826365,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>

  </Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: The posted KML is not valid.  Missing closing `</kml>` (possible typo).  `<open>` is not allowed in `<LookAt>`.  (But probably neither is the issue)

Comment: The KML was cut off somehow at the bottom, thanks.

Comment: If you want the balloon to automatically display when viewed initially then you need to add <gx:balloonVisibility> to your KML. See related question and answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841029/google-earth-balloon-at-launch

Answer (score 0):

here's the tame plate of  automatically balloon visibility, i hope it'll:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">

<Placemark>
<name>automatically balloon </name>
<description>
    Located in Paris, France. 

    This description balloon opens 
    when the Placemark is loaded.
</description>
<gx:balloonVisibility>1</gx:balloonVisibility>
<Point> 
  <coordinates>57.0833,30.2833,0</coordinates>
</Point>
</Placemark>

</kml>
```